# subdomains using NGINX and Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, nginx, subdomain

I'd like to have various subdomains on my site such as: `biology.mysite.com`.

Currently I have the following in my nginx.conf:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name biology.mysite.com;
  return 301  https://mysite.com/tags/biology$request_uri;
}
```

This code works in that if you point the browser to `biology.mysite.com`, it redirects to `https://mysite.com/tags/biology` and the correct biology content loads.

However, I **don't** want to redirect the url but want to keep the subdomain as the url.

So I replaced the above with the code below based on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/lynxluna/1050850) but it has no effect (meaning pointing to `biology.mysite.com` simply goes to `mysite.com`):

```
      if ($host ~* ^www\.([a-z0-9]*)\.(mysite\.com) )
      {
          set $tagname $1;
          set $host_without_www $2;
          rewrite ^/(.*)$ $scheme://$tagname.$host_without_www/ permanent;
      }

      if ($host ~* ^([a-z0-9]+)\.(mysite\.com))
      {
          set $tagname $1;
            set $host_without_www $2;

            rewrite ^/$ /index.php/tags/index/ last;
            rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php/$1 last;
      }
```

Thoughts?

**Note** the reason I posted this here rather than [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com) is b/c I'm using the Codeigniter framework (which has a unique routing scheme) and so the answer might involve knowledge of NGINX and Codeigniter.

Comment: you might want to wait a little bit.. sometimes it takes time for the server to adjust its settings.

Comment: @shnisaka thanks yes i've waited for about 30 minutes now, also that the first code block works shows that waiting is unlikely the issue.

Comment: @shnisaka :) lol ... 

timpeterson do you use nginx as standalone or as a proxy to apache ?

Comment: @ddjikic as a standalone

Comment: @timpeterson hmmm ... i know that as standalone it has some issues with php cgi im using it as a proxy and subdomains are configured in apache . nginx is great for caching static content and i have no issue with routing  ... but anyway i dont tihnk that is has any issue with CI

Comment: yeah i misspoke and don't think CI is the problem just wanted to remind readers that I'm using this framework. Do you see any reason my 2nd code block shouldn't work?

Comment: try this to make sure its not ci, make index.php as static test then load your browser to the subdomain. if you see the static text then its codeigniter and if thats the case try putting this into your config 

file $config['base_url'] = 
"http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['base_url'] .= preg_replace('@/+$@','',dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) . '/';

Comment: @Exploit so your `$config` code will work alongside my 2nd codeblock? Can you explain what your code is doing?

Comment: it automatically creates the base_url, i'm not sure if it will work but you can try and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your last rewrite should looks like below:

```
rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php/tags/$tagname$1 last;
```

**UPDATE:**
If you want to redirect requests like subdomain.mysite.com (WITHOUT uri part) to tags controller and use subdomain method you should change line below

```
rewrite ^/$ /index.php/tags/index/ last;
```

to

```
rewrite ^/$ /index.php/tags/$tagname/ last;
```

lynxluna's nginx configuration and comment in mentioned gist is wrong.